# Spring Security 4, not redrict after login

Tags: jsp, spring-security

Here is my Login page, `loginpage.jsp`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
<form name='f'action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/loginpage'method='POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my config file:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="mike" authorities="admin"
                password="letmein" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>



<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createroom" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreate" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginpage" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/room" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/loginpage" />
</security:http>
```

And here is my controller:

```
// this is my login controller
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/loginpage")
    public String showLogin(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
        // go to login page
        return "loginpage";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to redirect to?

Answer (score 1):

As per spring security form-login tag you must add default target url attribute. Such as.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/loginpage" default-target-url="/redirecturl"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to a default page you need to set default target url.
Check out this section of spring security for more information on what to set and where:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-target